# Magento: Forgotten Pword returns Blank Browser Page

Tags: php, magento

I really hope someone here can help out with this.

I'm using Magento 1.6.1.0 new install

If a customer clicks the forgotten password link on the frontend, they are sent an email with a link to click. When they click the link in the email, a blank white page is shown in the browser (no prompt to reset pword). The path when the email link is launched looks like this:

```
    www.mystore.com/customer/account/resetpassword/?id=4 token=26f8abcc1efd5559ce81ced2706586db

The "error_log" said:
30-Nov-2011 07:42:50] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function setCustomerId() on a non-object in /home3/bestcara/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountContr‌​oller.php on line 587
```

and here's the code block from AccountController.php

```
     * Display reset forgotten password form
 *
 * User is redirected on this action when he clicks on the corresponding link in password reset confirmation email
 *
 */
public function resetPasswordAction()
{
    $resetPasswordLinkToken = (string) $this->getRequest()->getQuery('token');
    $customerId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getQuery('id');
    try {
        $this->_validateResetPasswordLinkToken($customerId, $resetPasswordLinkToken);
        $this->loadLayout();
        // Pass received parameters to the reset forgotten password form
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('resetPassword')
            ->setCustomerId($customerId),<------------------------------------Line 587
            ->setResetPasswordLinkToken($resetPasswordLinkToken);
        $this->renderLayout();
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Your password reset link has expired.'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}
```

I really need to fix this as soon as possible. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Obviously an exception is firing somewhere, we'll need to know what it is to help you. Check what it is in the var/log/exception.log file. Ensure magento error logging is on.

Comment: Developer/Log Settings is enabled but I don't have var/log/exception.log anywhere. I read on the Magento forum you can check var/report/ folder for exception debug traces. There were 2 files in that directory. Does that help?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331574/magento-blank-page-customer-forgotten-password-email-link. Please only post your question once. This question should be removed.

Comment: I removed the above question from Joe Constan's comment. I added the correct answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like my theme was not supported for Magento 1.6.1.0

go to:
app/design/frontend/default/[your_custom_theme_folder]/layout/customer.xml

add these codes:

```
<customer_account_resetpassword translate="label">
    <label>Reset a Password</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/account_resetpassword" name="resetPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_resetpassword>
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: This worked for my with 1.7.0.2 but you must make sure that you clear all of your cache for this change to take effect!

Answer (score 0):

Check your customer.xml.

see answer on this link 
http://buyolx.blogspot.in/2015/03/magento-forgot-password-and-reset.html

---